# How can I use ssl in my MEAN.io applicationo

Tags: node.js, ssl, mean.io

I am a beginner.I just want to use SSL in my MEAN.io app.can someone tell me how can I use it in my mean.io app????
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use express-force-ssl by running

```
npm install express-force-ssl
```

In your server.js add the below code:

```
var forceSSL = require('express-force-ssl');

app.use(forceSSL);
```

Refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-force-ssl

Comment: Thanx. I will check it